# Is there a way to search email criteria and view the entire folder path for returned matches?

Tags: outlook

I work on a team with multiple other users and we archive our user emails in a shared Support inbox in Outlook. With thousands of emails being filed by multiple users, the filing system is imperfect and you often have to search through dozens of subfolders, wasting time.

**What I need is to be able to enter search criteria like this:**

FROM: 'Jane Doe'

TEXT IN EMAIL: "here's what happens when the server error message shows"

**And the search results should show:**

```
| FROM     | DATE      | SUBJECT                | FOLDER PATH                    |
|----------|-----------|------------------------|--------------------------------|
| Jane Doe | 1/28/2019 | Server Error Message?? | Inbox > User Support > Network |
```

This would allow me to find the latest thread of emails quickly without searching through dozens of subfolders looking for where the last team member filed the thread.

**Is this possible via VBA, Powershell, or out-of-the-box?**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that out of the box - Outlook will not show the path. But you can retrieve the path programmatically: `MailItem.Parent` returns the parent `MAPIFolder` object, so you can recursively go up the hierarchy using `MAPIFolder.Parent`.

Comment: Can you clarify - is your suggested solution to use VBA or Powershell? If so, do you have any recommended resources to create a simple script to achieve a proof of concept? I have programming experience, but not with those two tools.

Comment: It does not matter - Outlook does not know or care whether it is being accessed from VBA or PowerShell. I do not have any sample scripts I can share - but it is really simple: create a function that takes a folder as a parameter and returns a string by calling itself recirsively and concatenating the value it returns with the Name property of the current MAPIFolder object. Call that function passing the Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Parent